# Black Patches on Watermelon Peperomia

Tags: diagnosis, leaves

[image][image]

My Watermelon Peperomia that I purchased about 3 weeks ago keeps turning black! The leaves get cracks in them and then get these thin black areas that spread. There does not appear to be pests on the soil or leaves. I am watering sparingly, when the top 1" feels dry. Help!

Comment: Please check the underside of the leaves, preferably with a magnifying glass,in case there are invaders of some  sort underneath. Otherwise,  is the plant receiving direct sun, or is it near a heat source, or somewhere physical damage can be caused (like brushing past or knocking the leaves)?

Answer (score 1):

This could be simply mechanical damage. Many leaves are thin and can survive light mechanical bending or bruising with no detrimental effects. Other leaves are thicker - when these leaves are substantially bent or bruised this results in damage to cell walls or disruption of conductive tissues. The fractured cells then attempt to repair the surface by drying out and sealing against further loss of tissue or entry of infection.

Peperomia has thick leaves, and damage can affect the top or underside or both of the leaves. You can check this possibility by choosing a leaf that you will likely remove anyway, take a photo of it, cause some additional damage by bending or surface cutting, wait a few days and then compare the new result to the old.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue and have read the cause is "hard" tap water being used in watering. I am going to use filtered water from now on and hopefully that helps.